# Forgetting to take a Vps card / settlement of road after purchasing in Catan

Tags: catan

Good day all, hope ur doing well. A quick question since I never found anything in the rules of Catan. After a player purchased a Vps card/ road or settlement and forgets to take the card or item doest that mean I lose the purchase totally if the next round of die was played? Eg player A purchased a Vps card but forgot to take it and player B takes his turn does the Vps card fall away since the next round started?

Any help ?

Comment: Do you mean Development Card?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/39170/forgetting-to-place-a-city-on-the-board-or-to-move-the-robber-which-fix-is-acc

Comment: Your question is, at its core, "what to do when the rules are violated"? Ultimately, the rules in Catan (like most games) do not cover irregularities and so the answer is, at its core, "whatever your group can agree to" (or "whatever the tournament organizer says" if you're in a tournament).